# using text as background of a DIV

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to get a piece of text in the background of a DIV with controls showing over it. I have the effect ready, but the menu is over the text, the text is causing the links in the menu not to work anymore. I created a jsfiddle to show what I mean:

http://jsfiddle.net/aBqw8/1/

does anybody have a solution?

Answer (score 6):

How about adding...

```
z-index: -1;
```

to the `span.title` ruleset?

Comment: I made it a little harder for myself: I wanted to align the title to the right side of the DIV, but that does seem to mess things up...

Comment: @raina77ow, indeed, and I see now why this doesn't work for me... I didn't post the correct problem here. I am building this in bootstrap. If you do this in a div with a background color (a well) it doesn't work... http://jsfiddle.net/aBqw8/21/. It works if I remove the background color from the well, you think I should post this bew problem as a new question instead?

Comment: @patrick Yes, I would do that. ) This is a valid question on its own, and may be helpful to some other people; therefore, I think, it should be a separate one.

Comment: New question posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12932836/background-text-in-a-bootstrap-well

Answer (score 0):

Set the title's Z-index to something like -999 in the stylesheet