# Background text in a Bootstrap WELL

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem putting a text in the background of a Bootstrap well. I first posted the problem [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12920339/using-text-as-background-of-a-div), but that was a too simple representation of my problem. I'm looking for an effect created [in this jFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aBqw8/20/), a text in the background of a menu. The example works how I want to to work, but when I put this in a Bootstrap Well I get [this (http://jsfiddle.net/aBqw8/21/)](http://jsfiddle.net/aBqw8/21/).

The background text disappears, it's probably behind the Well. When I remove the background color from the well I can see the text. If I remove the "position:relative" from the span it shows the title, but then it interferes with the menu, which is what I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

change z-index to from -1 to a positive (I like it at 1000 so it's always on top) in the CSS

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aBqw8/22/

Comment: the z-index of which element do you mean?

Comment: Have you checked the fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/aBqw8/21/)? It is set at -1, that puts it behind the DIV making the title completely invisible... so this solution doesn't work

Comment: If I understood your question, you want the text to appear on top of the menu, correct?

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, you want the text to appear on top of the menu. Correct?  If yes, then this works as I said:


.title{
    position:relative;
    text-align:right;
    display:block;
    font-size:47px;
    font-weight:bold;
    opacity:0.2;
    z-index: 1000;
}

Comment: It might be my Chrome browser, but your Fiddle doesn't work. It's close, but as soon as the mouse comes close to the title it will loose hover of the menu item. Try clicking on the very top of the 'menu2' button the menu. Doesn't work here... Tried Safari and IE too, same problem

Comment: I appreciate your help and time in getting this solved Avi, but your solution is a workaround really. I am looking for the effect in http://jsfiddle.net/aBqw8/20/, if you make the screen small enough you can see the title acting like it's in the background, like a background image would normally do. The menu shows over the background text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**HTML**

```
<div class='well'>
    <div class='bg-title'>
      <span class='title'>TITLE GOES HERE</span>
    </div>
    <ul class='nav nav-pills'>
        <li><a href='#'>menu1</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>menu2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.bg-title {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.title {
    display: block;
    font-size: 47px;
    font-weight: bold;
    opacity: 0.2;
    position: relative;
    text-align: right;
    top: 37px; // whatever ...
    z-index: 90; // Must be behind your .nav-pills, if you use "-1" it will go behind the .well!
}

.nav-pills {
    //include ...
    z-index: 99;
}
```

**Watch out:** Bootstrap is using z-index: 1000 to 1050 for some of its elements - so try not to use this range or you might end up in another conflict - check _variables.scss (or .less)